# if condition with multiple grep commands not working

Tags: bash, grep

The following bash snippet gives "conditional binary operator expected"

```
countries=$1
while read -r line; do
        if [[ echo "$line" | grep BUSINESS | grep -E "$countries" ]]; then
                echo $line >> "$Business_Accounts"
        fi
done
```

What's going wrong?

Comment: `[[` has a syntax of its own, you can't put arbitrary shell commands in there like that. To test the return status of a pipeline just use it in the `if` directly. `if echo | grep | grep; then`. To test the output from the pipeline as non-empty wrap the pipeline in `$()` in the `[[`.

Comment: change the if statement to `if [[ $(echo "$line" | grep BUSINESS | grep -E "$countries") ]]; then`

Comment: actually both of you suggested a common thing - evaluating the result of a pipeline by $() & thats what worked for me.

Comment: @EtanReisner I had no idea that was valid

Comment: @ssdecontrol That's all `[` is doing for you. It is a command (and a built-in) which just returns a value. It isn't part of the `if` statement syntax (though many people think that).

Comment: @EtanReisner i actually did know that; it's an alias for `test`, no? What I didn't know is that bash could parse those pipes correctly without some kind of delimiter, but I guess that's what the semicolon is for

Comment: @ssdecontrol Yes, `[` and `test` are the same thing. Parse what pipes? The shell handles pipes all the time. You mean in the `if ....; then` context? The `...` can be any valid shell statement (as far as I know). `if if true; then true; fi; then echo foo; fi` works too. And the `;` is just to put `then` on the same line, a newline would work there instead too.

Comment: @EtanReisner exactly what I meant, +1 for the explanation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just change your `if` statement like below,

```
if [[ $(echo "$line" | grep BUSINESS | grep -E "$countries") ]]; then
```

OR

You could do like the above in a single grep command like in the below example because grep or awk or sed processes the input line by line.

```
$ contries="foo"
$ echo 'foo BUSINESS bar
bar' | grep -P "^(?=.*BUSINESS).*$con"
foo BUSINESS bar
$ Business_account=$(echo 'foo BUSINESS bar                                
bar' | grep -P "^(?=.*BUSINESS).*$con")
$ echo "$Business_account"
foo BUSINESS bar
```

In a single line, it would be like,

```
Business_account=$(grep -P "^(?=.*BUSINESS).*$contries" file)
```

Comment: or just `if echo "$line" | grep BUSINESS | grep -Eq "$countries"; then` ? `grep` has exit codes.

Comment: This solves the stated problem, but is a terrible way to actually filter lines from an input stream.

Comment: @chepner what's a better solution?

Comment: The `while` loop is just reimplementing `grep`, which already will apply the given regular expression to each line of the input.